# Remove Style in Materializecss inputs

Tags: materialize

How can completely remove the styling of inputs in materializecss? Changing the CSS alone doesn't seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

Use the Materialize class "browser-default".

For example:

```
<input type="text" class="browser-default"/>
```

Documentation here: http://materializecss.com/helpers.html#browser-default.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to remove the styling of inputs in materializecss is to download the sass file and remove the elements you dont wish to be imported. After that you just have to compile sass to css.

View the source of [this](http://use1ess.bplaced.net/stack/materialize_no_forms.html) if you want to download the compiled css file from which the input styling was removed.

[How to install/use sass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tE9_gDWZXDw)